# Eclipse Luna - GWT Deploy module on application server is disabled

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, web-deployment, eclipse-luna

I've downloaded Eclipse Luna and install the following Google's plugins:
Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.4
Google Web Toolkit SDK 2.6.0 Bundle for Eclipse
GWT Designer Development Mode Support
GWT Designer Editor
GWT Designer GPE

I've checkout an svn project which was initially created using Eclipse Indigo.
When I try to deploy the project I see that the "GWT Deploy module on application server" button is disable. On Indigo I didn;t encounter this problem.

I would appreciate any help figuring out how to enable it.

Many Thanks!